# How to revert to Apple ID user picture

Tags: catalina, user-account, login-screen

After a fresh install of MacOS Catalina, the OS will use a user icon or picture taken from the user's Apple ID and this will be displayed at login by default. If a user changes the user icon manually via the Users & Groups preference pane, how can they then revert to using the picture associated with the Apple ID?

I can delete the picture with `dscl . -delete /Users/username JPEGPhoto` which then reverts to an Anonymous User icon but signing out and back in with the Apple ID does not revert to the image associated with the Apple ID.